# Calling String equality operator from a typealiased override in Swift

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, type-alias

I was hoping to have a cheap string type that would allow a particular comparison of certain "special strings". However the following code ends up in infinite recursion:

```
typealias SpecialString = String
private extension SpecialString {
    var normalized: String {
        return lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }

    static func ==(lhs: SpecialString, rhs: SpecialString) -> Bool {
        return lhs.normalized == rhs.normalized
    }
}

assert(SpecialString("A B C") == SpecialString("abc"))
```

Is it possible to force usage of the `String.==` operator in my own comparison implementation? Or is this an unavoidable limitation of the way `typealias` works?

Comment: I think you might be able to redefine `==` for your string, but only if you subclass `String`, an extension will call the same method indefinitely.

Comment: This is a rather non-obvious definition of equality of a type, and I don't think it's suitable to hide it behind the general use `==` operator. I would suggest something like `isEqualAfterNormalization(to:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't currently possible. Typealiases are transparent aliases to the type they point to. `SpecialString` and `String` are exactly equivalent to the typesystem.

The closest thing you can do is make a new `SpecialString` wrapper, that wraps a `String`, exposes a read-only view into the wrapped string, and implements any custom methods you want. It would also help to make your `SpecialString` conform to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` and `CustomStringDescribable`.

Comment: "`SpecialString` and `String` are exactly equivalent to the typesystem" — but then why does adding an `assert("A B C" != "abc")` not lead to the same infinite recursion?

Comment: @natevw I don't understand, why would it lead to a recursion?

Comment: Because if the two types are exactly equivalent, then shouldn't my check between two strings also end up hitting my special override too?

Comment: Ah, sorry: `assert("abc" == "abc")` does infinite recurse — the `!=` check must not rely on the `==` operator.

Comment: @natevw A `==` operator defined within a type body has higher precedence than a freely defined `==` operator. I'm not sure why it's legal to have both, but there's no reason why that would cause recursion

Comment: @natevw Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, your `==` call is recursive. My point was that in principle, it's possible to implement a `static func ==` that takes higher precedence than the freely defined `func ==`, and that it could work just fine, assuming you don't have an unconditional recursive call, as you did.